# Question on deploying winform project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I want to seperate one project from my main winform project, then "publish" it or something so that i will be able to click a button and the application will run, instead of running visual C# expresss and then run the project.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean, but just building your Windows Forms application will create a .exe file - you can copy that (along with any DLLs it requires) to another machine which has the appropriate .NET framework on, and then just double-click on the executable to launch it. (You can copy it to elsewhere on the same machine as well, of course.)

You certainly *can* create "setup" projects to bundle everything into an installer, but for simple needs copying a file would be fine. You don't need to launch it through Visual Studio.

Comment: I do want to bundle an installer cause the application uses some pictures..i want the pictures to be placed in C:.. also where are those exe file lie

Comment: right click on the project file tab inside visual studio and select open containing folder or similar option.

Comment: @Dmitry: Do you really *need* the pictures to be outside the program? Can't they just be embedded resources? That would make deployment simpler. In my experience setup projects can be very complicated to create and maintain. Maybe that was just the projects I was using them for, of course...

Comment: How do I seperate one project when it is included into another project.. I have my chess game inside games project (with more games in it) ..how do I seperate it and put it into a new project?

Comment: jon, they can, but i already set all my algorithm being dependent on pictures being outside the projct

Comment: @Dmitry: Create new projects within the solution (or in different solutions) and just move the code over. If you have common code that multiple projects rely on, put that common code in a class library project. Likewise it shouldn't be too hard to change your code to use an embedded resource, unless you need to *write* to the files as well as reading from them. I would say that's likely to be easier than creating a deployment project.

Comment: alright..i achieved what i wanted... I copied the whole games project deleted all the games from the copy apart from chess.. in  : Application.Run(... I changed to new Chess()) instead of ..new Games().. now i can play chess.. but how can i press an exe file and run the game directly

Comment: I also want to make a game icon on the desktop.. something like a desktop shortcut..and i want it to have a picture

Comment: @Dmitry: Well, you can include an icon within your executable (IIRC) and you can create a shortcut yourself if you want to. If you want to distribute this to people then yes, you possibly *do* want an installer - but you need to be prepared for it to be *potentially* quite a bit of work, that's all.

Comment: is there a link , you know of that explains the process

Comment: @Dmitry: Search for "Visual Studio setup project" and you'll find loads of guides. For example, see http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your application as Windows app, it is executable out of VS environment. Just change the properites of the project.

And what do you mean click a button? From desktop, you need to double/single click the application from its directory to launch it.

Again qs is not clear.

Comment: why isnt clear..i want to click a shortcut to run my chess application not visual express